# Recursive Sudoku solver not solving anything

Tags: python, sudoku

I was working on a Sudoku solver, and when I ran it, it just didn't work- the function f returned a none type. After debugging, I found out the code didn't solve some of the squares. I don't know why this happened, but I suspect the loop checking all the numbers possible in a square stops after finding one possible number and doesn't check the rest too. Can you please pinpoint me the problem in my code? Thanks.

Note: for empty spaces in the Sudoku, enter 0.

```
# enter the Sudoku as a two-dimensional array (a[i][j])

def square_check(array, loc_x, loc_y, val):
    added_x = loc_x - (loc_x % 3)
    added_y = loc_y - (loc_y % 3)
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if i+added_y != loc_y or j+added_x != loc_x:
                if array[i+added_y][j+added_x] == val:
                    return False
    return True


def line_check(array, loc_x, loc_y, val):
    for i in range(9):
        if i != loc_x:
            if array[loc_y][i] == val:
                return False
    return True


def col_check(array, loc_x, loc_y, val):
    for i in range(9):
        if i != loc_y:
            if array[i][loc_x] == val:
                return False
    return True


def f(array):
    flag = True
    mark = True
    for i in range(0, 9):
        for j in range(0, 9):
            if array[i][j] == 0:
                flag = False
    if flag:
        return array

    for i in range(0, 9):
        for j in range(0, 9):
            if array[i][j] == 0:
                for num in range(1, 10):
                    if square_check(array, j, i, num):
                        if col_check(array, j, i, num):
                            if line_check(array, j, i, num):
                                new_array = array.copy()
                                new_array[i][j] = num
                                mark = False
                                f(new_array)
                if mark:
                    break


def to_str(array):
    for i in range(len(array)):
        print(array[i])
    print("")


to_str(f(sudoku))
```

Comment: This might be interesting for you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_UYXzGuqvM

Comment: thanks, gave me some ideas on how to improve.

Comment: You ignore the return value of f

Comment: fixed that, now enters an infinite loop

Comment: problem was solved. solver now works